# How to call foreach result in to another function?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have a controller file, in this page two functions are there. I need testone functionality in testtwo function. So I called the testone() inside testtwo() but getting an error "`Array to string conversion error`"

When I print_r($title), result is listing ont the page //Array ( [0] => Turbo [1] => Turboboost [2] => Monoboost ).

**Customercontoller.php**

```
public function testone($id)
    {
        $title = array();
        $hardwares = Hardware::select('hardwares.title')
            ->join('vehicle_hardwares', 'hardwares.id', '=', 'vehicle_hardwares.hardware_id')
            ->where('vehicle_hardwares.vehicle_id', $id)
            ->where('hardwares.status', 'online')
            ->get();
        foreach ($hardwares as $hardware){
            $title[] = $hardware->title;
        }
        return $title;
        //print_r($title); //Array ( [0] => Turbo [1] => Turboboost [2] => Monoboost )
    }



protected function testtwo($customer_id)
 {
  $vehicleList ='';
  $vehicle_id  = 1;
  $vehicleList .=' <p>Details: '.$this->testone($vehicle_id).'</p><br>'
  return $vehicleList;
 }
```

Comment: `$this->testone($vehicle_id)` returns `$title` which is an array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$title` is array not string . you can't concatenate string with array

You need to return string from `testone` function

```
$title = "";
foreach ($hardwares as $hardware) {
    $title .= "<p>Details: " . $hardware->title . "</p><br>";
}
return $title;// return string
```

And get in `testtwo` as

```
$vehicleList .=$this->testone($vehicle_id);
return $vehicleList;
```

Comment: Thank you so much I got it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `testone` function returns an array of strings, you need to iterate the array in your `testtwo` function.

Answer (score 1):

This line returns array

```
$this->testone($vehicle_id)
```

so during concatenation

```
$vehicleList .=' <p>Details: '.$this->testone($vehicle_id).'</p><br>'
```

PHP internally tries to convert array to string which it can't do and thus ends up with `array to string conversion` error.

if you are using the PHP7.0 you can use following syntax to destructure the PHP array.

```
$vehicleList .=' <p>Details: '.$this->testone()[$vehicle_id].'</p><br>'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an array

```
return $title;
```

And you are using it as a string here

```
$vehicleList .=' <p>Details: '.$this->testone($vehicle_id).'</p><br>'
```

That's why you are having this error. You need to return the string from `testone()`